# I can't find When Web1.GotText block in app inventor 2

Tags: app-inventor

[Code I need to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z39qS.png)
[image]
The picture is the code Im following but I can't find the yellow block in my block area can anyone tell me how to?

I tried going to the Web1 blocks but I was unable to find it, maybe I have to make a function or something else

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `Web` component needs to be on the app screen. If it isn't, then the following steps need to be taken:

1. Make sure you are on the `Designer` view.
2. Open the `Connectivity` section in the `Palette` (on the left side of the screen).
3. Drag the `Web` component anywhere onto the screen preview (inside the phone frame).

Next open the `Blocks` view. On the left under the blocks section select the `Web1` component. A menu should appear listing the built-in blocks. The `When Web1.GotText` block should be at the top of the menu. (An example image is below)

Note: The blocks menu is scrolled to where you were when you last had it open.

The following image is when the Web1 blocks panel is open.
[image: A MIT App Inventor project with only a Web component in it. The blocks panel for Web1 is open and scrolled to the top to show the block that is trying to be located]

Comment: One more question, where can I get the Purple block named call resetform?

Comment: resetform is a custom procedure.... you should do some tutorials to learn the basics... see also http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/blocks/procedures.html